# python for loop only updates 2 of 3 variables?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter, listbox

I want to use 3 variables in one for loops.
This is what I tried:

```
def loop_player_listbox():
    global bol_loop, count
    bol_loop = True
    while True:
        
        time.sleep(1)
        str_libo_p = listbox.get(0,tk.END)
        str_libo_r = listboxr.get(0,tk.END)
        str_libo_price = listboxprice.get(0,tk.END)

        for i,r,p in itertools.product(str_libo_p, str_libo_r, str_libo_price):
            text_playername = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,('/html/body/main/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input'))))
            text_playername.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            text_playername.clear()
            time.sleep(1)
            text_playername.click()
            text_playername.send_keys(i)
            user_input_max_price = p
            try:
                choose_player = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("//span[@class='btn-text' and contains(text(),'"+i+"')]")))) and wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,("//span[@class='btn-subtext' and contains(text(),'"+r+"')]"))))
                choose_player.click()
                
                count = 0
                while count < 5:

                    while True:
                        # some unimportant code

                    # set speed
                    # some unimportant code

                    # set max BIN price
                    while True:
                        #user_input_max_price = input('Enter max buy now price (>250):')
                        user_input_max_price = p
                        if user_input_max_price.isdigit():
                            int_user_input_max_price = int(user_input_max_price)
                            if int_user_input_max_price > 250:
                                break
                            else:
                                print('Max buy now price must be >250')
                                continue
                        else:
                            continue
                            

                    
                    # set max price
                    # some unimportant code


                    # Buy until 100 players were bought
                    while count < 5:            
                        
                        # some unimportant code
                        count +=1
```

The problem is, variable `r` and `p` do update after `count = 5`.

But `i` is always only showing the first item from my listbox and does not update. Every time my loop is coming back to the line `for i,r,p ...` I see in debug that only the variables `r` and `p` updated.

I have no idea why. While searching for how to combine more than one `for`loops I found `itertools`and so I used it.

Maybe anyone sees whast wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changed from itertools to zip fixed the issue.

`for i,r,p in zip(str_libo_p, str_libo_r, str_libo_price):`